# Binding class doesn't seem to work properly based on attached variable value

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

My `banner-visible` binding class is conditioned by my `showMainBanner` computed property:

```
<div :class="['view view-index', { 'banner-visible' : showMainBanner }]">
```

Here's how I define my computed property:

```
computed: {
  showMainBanner () {
    return (Cookies.get('banner_dismiss')) ? false : this.$store.state.config.showMainBanner
  }
}
```

When I reload the page, I can see the value of my computed property by console logging it in the `mounted()` hook:

```
mounted () {
  console.log('showMainBanner = ' + this.showMainBanner)
}
```

In the console on page load I see: `showMainBanner = false`

Yet, the `banner-visible` class is still there, despite the value of showMainBanner being false.

How is that possible?

The most puzzling thing is this: when I navigate the page away through a link, and come back to it through a link, this problem does NOT occur. But if I refresh the page, it does.

EDIT:

I changed my code to something even more explicit:

```
showMainBanner () {
  if (Cookies.get('banner_dismiss')) {
    console.log('RETURN FALSE')
    return false
  } else {
    console.log('RETURN TRUE')
    return this.$store.state.config.showMainBanner
  }
}
```

After refreshing the page, I see in the console RETURN FALSE and I still see `showMainBanner = false` from the `console.log()` call in `mounted()` hook. So clearly, `showMainBanner` is *definitely* equal to `false`.

Is there black magic going on here?

Comment: are you able to show what data value your computed value is dependent on? I am thinking that during page refresh the data value that your computed value is dependent on is never updated hence the odd behavior, but the showMainBanner computed property evaluates to false in console.log when you refresh the page, so it could also be an issue in the array syntax of your class binding. Did you try changes to the array syntax? like doing `<div v-bind:class="[view, view-index, { banner-visible : showMainBanner }]">` or something like that?

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I'm getting compiling errors:  `'v-bind' directives require an attribute value` and `Parsing error: Line 1: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: yes data needs to be declared for those classes like `data { view: 'view', view-index: 'view-index' }`. At any rate, it seems that the truthy condition is true even when the return is false. I am not sure if it evaluates to true as long as there is a return value, can you try and return `null` instead of `false`? also try separating the classes and set the consition as false like `:class="['view','view-index', { 'banner-visible' : false }]"` then try refreshing.

Comment: So it works whether I "manually" return `null` or `false`. This makes zero sense to me: if I return `false` manually it works, but if I return `false` "programmatically" it doesn't... Why?? It's `false` in both cases!

Comment: that means that the evaluation of `showMainBanner` is never changed when the page is refreshed , now the question is should you continue using a computed value because it seems that showMainBanner is not dependent on any data in the current function scope, so why not use an ordinary method for it?

Comment: I still don't understand how the `banner-visible` class is added by Vue since `showMainBanner` returns `false` (as I can see in the console)

Comment: Good question and the answer is related to how computed values are executed, they are executed when data is changed, or when directly called. I would assume that your `console.log` would execute the `showMainBanner` function again, resulting in the `false` return value, with that said and without knowing what data `showMainBanner` is dependent on, then I would lean towards fixing the data to update when the page is refreshed or just move your `showMainBanner` function inside `methods:` from `computed:`

Comment: Just did that, doesn't solve the issue unfortunately...

Comment: You should post a minimal reproducible example, in jsfiddle or alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`Cookies` is not reactive. After the first time `showMainBanner` is evaluated it does not get evaluated again by Vue.

When you navigate away and come back, Vue will evaluate the computed property again and this time the Cookie is already set.

Comment: This reactivity problem should be solved by navigating away from then back to the page, but also by refreshing the page isn't it? Yet it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because your cookie returns a string:

```js
console.log(typeof Cookies.get('banner_dismiss'))
//=> string
```

Try to change your condition like:

```js
computed: {
  showMainBanner () {
    let dismiss = Cookies.get('banner_dismiss') === 'undefined' ? false : JSON.parse(Cookies.get('banner_dismiss'))
    return dismiss ? false : this.$store.state.config.showMainBanner
  }
}
```

---

Or if you want to avoid JSON's errors in case of empty Cookie, you can add a plain condition:

```js
computed: {
  showMainBanner () {
    let dismiss = Cookies.get('banner_dismiss') === 'true'
    return dismiss ? false : this.$store.state.config.showMainBanner
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get a ` ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"` when doing that though and I'm not sure why

Comment: @drake035, it's because your Cookie is empty and returns `undefined` (it breaks the JSON.parse). Try to add anther condition like `if (Cookie.get('banner_dismiss') !== 'undefined')` based on whatever you need to return in that case/

Comment: Still got the same error at line: `const dismiss = (Cookies.get('banner_dismiss') !== 'undefined') && JSON.parse(Cookies.get('banner_dismiss'))`

Comment: @drake035 you right, I saw my mistake when I edited my answer. The `undefined` condition must be first THEN you parse the cookie (and not AND i.e. `&&`). I updated my answer... again :)

Comment: Done, I'm getting `ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"`

Comment: That's weird... anyway, you can remove the `JSON.parse` and just add a plain condition like `let dismiss = Cookies.get('banner_dismiss') === 'true'`. This way, you just check if the string returned is equal to string "true"

Comment: Works now. But doesn't solve the problem: `banner-visible` class still shows up, despite `console.log(Cookies.get('banner_dismiss'))` displaying `true` and `console.log(this.showMainBanner)` displaying `false` in console...